# In which professional sports league do players share the highest % of revenue?

Tags: finances

In which American professional sports league do players share the highest % of league revenue?

Any professional sports league is acceptable so long as most players rely on their participation as their primary source of income (please exclude hobby and semi pro leagues that cannot mean that description).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For three of the four major US sports leagues the players share the following percentage of revenue:

NFL: 58%
NBA: 57%
MLB: 53%

[Source found here.](http://www.investopedia.com/financial-edge/0810/whos-cashing-in-on-pro-sports-revenue.aspx)